# Issue with saving cyrillic symbols to MSSQL via unixODBC and FreeTDS

Tags: django, pyodbc, freetds, unixodbc

My environment is quite qimilar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11869044/issue-with-returning-cyrillic-symbols-from-mssql-via-unixodbc-and-freetds)

All non-unicode data from database are displayed correctly.
I am able to save some data to database (both ascii and cyrillic). Standard ascii characters are then displayed correctly, but Cyrillic data displayed like this

> Р В Р’В Р вЂ™Р’В Р В РІР

How can I find the point where wrong encode/decode operetion takes place?

Comment: Just debug your program. Follow each step and verify the data is still correct at each point. Not really something we can help with, especially without any lines of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved a problem.
The correct database configuration in settings.py file is:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'db',
        'USER': 'user',
        'PASSWORD': 'pass',
        'HOST': '192.168.11.11',
        'PORT': '3306',
    },
    'mssql': {
        'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': True,
        'NAME': 'DB',
        'ENGINE': 'django_pyodbc',
        'USER': 'admin',
        'PASSWORD': 'pass',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'dsn': 'DBDSN',
            'host_is_server': True,
            'collation': 'Cyrillic_General_CI_AS',
            'driver_supports_utf8': True,
            'unicode_results':  True,
            'autocommit': True,
        },
    }
}
```

/etc/freetds/freetds.conf

```
[global]
tds version = 7.3
text size = 64512

[SRV]
host = mssql.local
port = 1433
```

/etc/odbc.ini

```
[ODBC Data Sources]
DBDSN = Microsoft SQL Server

[DBDSN]
Driver = FreeTDS
Servername = SRV
Trace = No
Database = DB
```

/etc/odbcinst.ini

```
[FreeTDS]
Description = FreeTDS
Driver = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
Setup = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsS.so
UsageCount = 1
```

The important point is that odbc.ini and odbsinst.ini files should NOT contain spaces or tabs in the begining of the lines.
These settings allows cyrillic symbols to be normally inserted into database.